# Difference between two .csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

First Exported .csv file (Report of First Day)

```
id                                      principalName       licenseDisplayName    

4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    abc@my.com         Basic   
5b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    xyz@my.com         Stackholder   
6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    pqr@my.com         Admin
```

Another Day export .csv file (Report of Second Day)

```
id                                      principalName       licenseDisplayName    

4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    abc@my.com         Stackholder   
5b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    xyz@my.com         Stackholder   
8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    yz@my.com          Basic
```

Scenario, there is daily export report using PowerShell. In above Report 1 and Report 2 shows the records. So, I wanted difference between two .csv files.

In Report2, the first record is changed from `Basic` to `Stackholder` and the third record is missing `6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d` and a new record  `8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d` is added

I wanted the following output (Difference of the two .csv files)

```
id                                     principalName       licenseDisplayName       Status    
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    abc@my.com         Stackholder     Updated from Basic to Stackholder
6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    pqr@my.com         Admin             Deleted
8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    yz@my.com          Basic               New
```

My code:

```
$reference = Import-Csv -Path C:\Documents\Daily_Report\Daily_Export_jsonold.csv
$lookup = $reference | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Server
$results = Import-Csv -Path C:\Documents\Daily_Report\Daily_Export_jsonnew.csv | foreach {
    $server = $_.id
    Write-Verbose "Looking for $server"
    if ($lookup.value.ContainsKey($server))
    {
        $oldState = ($lookup[$server]).Access_Level
    }
    
    if ($_.State -ne $oldState)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            id = $server
            Username = $_.Username
            OldState = $oldState
            NewState = $_.Access_Level
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following output

```
id                                   Username                  OldState NewState   
--                                   --------                  -------- --------   
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d abc@my.com                Unknown  Stakeholder
5b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d xyz@my.com                Unknown  Stakeholder
```

I wanted it to be like below:

```
id                                   Username             OldState     NewState   
--                                   --------             --------     --------   
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d abc@my.com           Basic        Stakeholder
5b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d xyz@my.com           Stakeholder  Stakeholder
```

Comment: I voted this down because it doesn't show any research effort or attempts at solving. Can you please update your question with what you have tried so far and what errors you're getting?

Comment: I wanted Report 1 And Report 2 difference using powershell

Comment: Okay... What have you tried so far? What specific errors are you getting? Have you done any research? I know for a fact that there is this exact question on the TechNet forum because I asked it when I was first getting started. However, I included examples of what I'd tried and the issues I was getting. We aren't just going to write a script for you...

Comment: I have try above snippet of powershell. In that, column oldstate I wanted output "Basic" of 1st row and second row as it is not change @I.T Delinquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to let the cmdlet `Compare-Object` do the core of the work.

```
$Reference = Import-Csv '.\Daily_Export_jsonold.csv'
$Difference= Import-Csv '.\Daily_Export_jsonnew.csv'

Compare-Object -Ref $Reference -Diff $Difference `
               -Property id,principalName,licenseDisplayName
```

Sample output:

```
id                                   principalName licenseDisplayName SideIndicator
--                                   ------------- ------------------ -------------
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d abc@my.com    Stackholder        =>
8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d yz@my.com     Basic              =>
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d abc@my.com    Basic              <=
6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d pqr@my.com    Admin              <=
```

That's quite near your desired result, grouping this by the property `id` yields:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848... {@{id=4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d; principalName=abc@my.com; licenseDisplayName=Stackho...
    1 8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848... {@{id=8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d; principalName=yz@my.com; licenseDisplayName=Basic; S...
    1 6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848... {@{id=6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d; principalName=pqr@my.com; licenseDisplayName=Admin; ...
```

Here:

- Count greater one denotes a change
- Count of 1 and a SideIndicator `'<='` denotes 'Deleted'
- Count of 1 and a SideIndicator `'=>'` denotes 'New'

So this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\28\SO_56341395.ps1
$Reference = Import-Csv '.\Daily_Export_jsonOld.csv'
$Difference= Import-Csv '.\Daily_Export_jsonNew.csv'

$Result = Compare-Object -Ref $Reference -Diff $Difference `
               -Property id,principalName,licenseDisplayName |
    Group-Object id | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Count -gt 1){
            $Status = 'Updated from {0}' -f $_.Group[1].licenseDisplayName
        } elseif ($_.Group[0].SideIndicator -eq '<='){
            $Status = 'Deleted'
        } else {
            $Status = 'New'
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            id                 = $_.Group[0].id
            principalName      = $_.Group[0].principalName
            licenseDisplayName = $_.Group[0].licenseDisplayName
            Status             = $Status
        }
    }

$Result | Sort-Object id
$Result | Sort-Object id| Export-Csv '.\Daily_Export_jsonDif.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Yields this output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\28\SO_56341395.ps1

id                                   principalName licenseDisplayName Status
--                                   ------------- ------------------ ------
4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d abc@my.com    Stackholder        Updated from Basic
6b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d pqr@my.com    Admin              Deleted
8b3556f1-ff58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d yz@my.com     Basic              New
```

Comment: Thanks lot @LotPings.Nice Solution.